# I am asking user to enter the size and array but when I am printing the vector it shows '0' only as output

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop

I declared a vector and trying to put size and values and printing it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int s;          
    cin>>s;                   //taking size of vector
    vector <int> arr(s);
    int input;
    while (cin >> input)
       {arr.push_back(input);}     //inserting the values in array
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        cout<<" "<<arr[i];         //printing the values
}
```

My input
5

1 2 3 4 5

Expected output

1 2 3 4 5

Current output
0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Because you have 10 elements and printing the first 5.

Comment: @cdhowie that was small ' i ' in the real code I accidently put ' I ' here .

Comment: @Suthiro The size of vector will be entered by user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
vector <int> arr(s);
```

makes `arr` have the size `s`. It will have `s` elements that have been default-initialized to 0. Then you are doing `push_back` on this vector, which adds *additional* elements into the vector.

When you print out the first `s` elements, you are not seeing the values that were read from `cin`, but the `s` number of initial values created in the declaration of `arr`.

To fix this, either don't give a size when you declare `arr`, or else just use `arr[i] = input;` instead of `push_back()` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement to create the vector didn't just create it, it filled it with 5 default values.  For integers the default value is 0.

```
vector <int> arr(s);
```

Just look at all the overloads for the [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

You probably didn't want that, what you wanted was to reserve 5 spaces in the vector because you knew you were going to push 5 values.  You do that with [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

```
vector <int> arr;
arr.reserve(s);
```

Comment: Very glad to see an answer on the linked dupe, instead of the latest question :)

Comment: @cigien thanks but it was all an accident of timing.  It would have ended up on the latest question if it hadn't been closed before I finished.  I figured copying it here was better than losing it forever.  And thanks for identifying the duplicate, sometimes that's the hardest job.