# Ambiguity in Vector Size

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, vector

I've just started using C++ stl's vector containers and I noticed this ambiguity in the vector size.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main(){
    int n=5;
    std::vector<int> vec(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        vec.push_back(i*3);
    }


    
    std::cout<<vec.size()<<endl;
    for(auto it:vec){
        std::cout<<it<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
10
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 6 9 12
```

As far as I know the vector size should have been 5 but it seems there's something wrong with either the compiler or is it that I'm missing something essential in vectors ?

Comment: You create a vector with 5 default constructed values, then push_back 5 more values.  10 values.

Comment: Oops, was about to close as [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561729/i-am-asking-user-to-enter-the-size-and-array-but-when-i-am-printing-the-vector-i) Disclaimer, I wrote an answer there.

Comment: You can use `vec[i] = i*3;` instead of `vec.push_back(i*3);` because you already have 5 items in the vector. An alternate method would change `std::vector<int> vec(n);` to `std::vector<int> vec; vec.reserve(n);`  and leave the rest of the code alone.

Comment: Why was this closed?  It seems like a legitimate misunderstanding that is easy to fix.

Comment: @MarkRansom Agreed. But if it's opened, I'm going to close it as a dupe. So, I'm not sure if it's worth reopening.

Comment: @MarkRansom I voted to re-open. The question is it worth an answer or a simple comment as Eljay did.

Comment: I like it when the close reason makes sense.

Comment: @cigien didn't see your dupe until I asked.  I agree, the dupe covers it.

Comment: @TonyTannous I had an answer ready too, but it closed before I could post it.  Do check out the duplicate link though.

Comment: @MarkRansom the same as my answer with different wording. I will delete mine :)

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, wrong close reasons annoy me :) I just didn't feel comfortable reopening and closing as dupe, since I answered the dupe.

Comment: @cigien You're probably not the only one. Wouldn't be surprised if I have an answer for this problem somewhere on SO as well, but one dupe should be good enough. It's one of those things that's hard to search for until you know what the problem is, so it's understandable that it pops up semi-regularly.

Comment: @user4581301 Indeed, do you happen to know a good canonical? The dupe I linked to has less than 50 views :( I would love to close unnecessary dupes if I could.

Comment: @cigien Not of the top of my head, and I'm not surprised my quick google didn't come up with one. Not an easy one to search for.